# How to define an Analytic Journal for employee Administrator in Oddo 8?

Tags: odoo-8

With odoo 8, when trying to synch my system and Odoo trough the webservice, I get the following error.

```
    No 'Analytic Journal' is defined for employee Administrator 
    Define an employee for the selected user and assign an 'Analytic Journal'!
```

I use the Administrator account to connect to the webservice, I have access to everything I tested.

I am able to create my lines in *account.analytic.line* with journal and account references, but when trying to save the association to the sheet  in *hr.analytic.timesheet*, I get the error.

How to define an Analytic Journal for employee Administrator?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I can fixed 
Step
1. Go to old Employees Administrator Change Related User to blank
2. Create new Employees selected Related User Administrator